# Run Flask/Dash App with VSCode Debugger not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, visual-studio-code, plotly-dash

When I run my Dash app from the command line using

`export PYTHONPATH=./src/ && python ./src/pdv/app.py`

it runs properly, however, when I try to run it with the debugger (using the following `configuration` in my `launch.json`

```json
       {
           "name": "Python: Current File",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"}
        },
```

I get the following error:

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
No module named app
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my debug configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The file you are referring to is the **launch.json**, if the content of that file is contained within the **settings.json** file it cannot work.

I leave you an example of how the **settings.json** and **launch.json** files should be configured to debug a python application in visual studio code:

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "<YOUR_PYTHON_EXE_IN_VIRTUALENV_PATH>",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations" : [
        {
            "name": "local",
            "type": "python",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        }
    ]
}
```

At the following [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) you can find the **documentation** on how to set the debugger in visual studio code for a flask application

Comment: Indeed it was actually a typo, the code was in my `launch.json`... I've tried your configuration and I still get the same error... I.e. `No module named app`

Answer (score 0):

the code snippet in your article should belong to launch.json, paste it into setting.json will cause this error.You could create a new launch.json in the debug tab.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with same issue, I ended up just using the native Flask server instead of the Dash wrapper, by adding the following to my `launch.json`

```json
        {
            "name": "Debug pdv plots",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/",
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/src/pdv/app",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
            ],
        }
```